# Carbon convert no of days to human readable format

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I need to convert 30 days to 1 month .If months and days are means then like 1 years 2 month 2 days
I have tried below but it will return wrong result

```
 echo CarbonInterval::days(30)->cascade()->forHumans();
```

Can any one help me how i can achieve this ?

I have tried below solution but got only 2 days difference

```
$convert = '30'; // days you want to convert

    $years = ($convert / 365) ; // days / 365 days
    $years = floor($years); // Remove all decimals

    $month = ($convert % 365) / 30.5; // I choose 30.5 for Month (30,31) ;)
    $month = floor($month); // Remove all decimals

    $days = ($convert % 365) % 30.5; // the rest of days

    // Echo all information set
    echo 'DAYS RECEIVE : '.$convert.' days<br>';
    echo $years.' years - '.$month.' month - '.$days.' days';
```

Is there any good solution using carbon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it have to be CarbonInterval?

What about `Carbon::now()->subDays(1827)->diffForHumans()`?

The reason it doesn't work as you're expecting (from https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-interval):

> Default factors are:
>
> - 1 minute = 60 seconds
> - 1 hour = 60 minutes
> - 1 day = 24 hour
> - 1 week = 7 days
> - 1 month = 4 weeks
> - 1 year = 12 months
>
> CarbonIntervals do not carry context so they cannot be more precise
>   (no DST, no leap year, no real month length or year length
>   consideration).